# Escape Single Quotes Ansible 2.1

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Using Ansible 2.1,

```
ansible all -i 127.0.0.1, -m lineinfile   -a    "dest=/etc/engine/engine.json state=present regexp=\"rpc_json\" line='\"rpc_json\": \"127.0.0.1:54321\"',"
```

That commands works but adds

```
'"rpc_json": "127.0.0.1:54321"',
```

Please how do i remove the single quote, so i can have

```
"rpc_json": "127.0.0.1:54321",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is more bash question than ansible:

```
ansible all -i 127.0.0.1, -m lineinfile -a 'dest=/etc/engine/engine.json state=present regexp=rpc_json line='\''"rpc_json": "127.0.0.1:54321",'\'
```

In `'\''` first `'` closes string, then `\'` glues escaped single quote, then `'` starts next string to be glued.